# How to use read.csv2.sql to read zip file without unzipping it?

Tags: r, csv, zip

I am trying to read a zip file without unzipping it in my directory while utilizing `read.csv2.sql` for specific row filtering.

Zip file can be downloaded [here](https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/exdata%2Fdata%2Fhousehold_power_consumption.zip) :

I have tried setting up a file connection to `read.csv2.sql`, but it seems that it does not take in file connection as an parameter for "file".

I already installed `sqldf` package in my machine.

This is my following R code for the issue described:

```r
### Name the download file
zipFile <- "Dataset.zip"

### Download it
download.file("https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/exdata%2Fdata%2Fhousehold_power_consumption.zip",zipFile,mode="wb")

## Set up zip file directory
zip_dir <- paste0(workingDirectory,"/Dataset.zip")

### Establish link to "household_power_consumption.txt" inside zip file
data_file <- unz(zip_dir,"household_power_consumption.txt")

### Read file into loaded_df
loaded_df <- read.csv2.sql(data_file , sql="SELECT * FROM file WHERE Date='01/02/2007' OR Date='02/02/2007'",header=TRUE)

### Error Msg
### -Error in file(file) : invalid 'description' argument
```

Comment: AFAIK you can't do this, at least not as you plan, because `read.csv2.sql` does not work on ZIP files.

Answer (score 1):

This does not use `read.csv2.sql` but as there are only ~ 2 million records in the file it should be possible to just download it, read it in using `read.csv2` and then subset it in R.

```
# download file creating zipfile
u <-"https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/exdata%2Fdata%2Fhousehold_power_consumption.zip"
zipfile <- sub(".*%2F", "", u)
download.file(u, zipfile)

# extract fname from zipfile, read it into DF0 and subset it to DF 
fname <- sub(".zip", ".txt", zipfile)
DF0 <- read.csv2(unz(zipfile, fname))
DF0$Date <- as.Date(DF0$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
DF <- subset(DF0, Date == '2007-02-01' | Date == '2007-02-02')

# can optionally free up memory used by DF0
# rm(DF0)
```

Comment: Unzipping the file then remove it afterwards looks good. But I wish to explore more on the scenario where the file is not required to be unzipped for learning purpose.